# Stream.map not converting into Stream of streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

```
reportNames.stream().map(reportName -> {
        if(reportName.equalsIgnoreCase("品番別明細表")) {
            List<String> parts = fetchParts(form.getFacility(), form.getYear(), form.getMonth());
            return parts.stream().map(part ->
                ExcelReportForm.builder().facility(form.getFacility())
                    .month(form.getMonth())
                    .year(form.getYear())
                    .partNumber(part)
                    .build()
            );
        } else {
            return Collections.singletonList(ExcelReportForm.builder().facility(form.getFacility())
                    .month(form.getMonth())
                    .year(form.getYear())
                    .partNumber("")
                    .build());
        }
    }).flatMap(List::stream)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Basically what I am trying to do is - I am trying to map a `Stream<Object>`into `Stream<Stream<Object>>`, but somehow lambda doesn't understand the underlying type, and throws error on `.flatMap(List::stream)`

The error says `Non static method cannot be referenced from static context`.

I am wondering what might be causing this. Can someone help me please?

**UPDATE**

I figured out the answer as pointed out by @nullpointer.
I realized the code issue lying within after I extracted a separate method from the lambda expression. The new answer lies below -

```
reportNames.stream()
            .map(reportName -> mapReportNameToFormParams(form, reportName))
            .flatMap(stream -> stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Should your `map` call return a `Stream` or a `List`? You can't return one in the if clause and the other in the else clause.

Comment: If your `map` returns a `List`, this shall work fine.

Comment: yeah, I figured that out..Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is the type returned from your `map` operation is `Stream<T>` and not `List<T>`.

Inferring the above from

```
return parts.stream().map(part ->
    ExcelReportForm.builder().facility(form.getFacility())
        .month(form.getMonth())
        .year(form.getYear())
        .partNumber(part)
        .build()
);
```

You can either collect the above to return a `List<T>` and then proceed with the current code or instead apply the `flatMap` to a `Stream<Stream<T>>` you can rather use identity operation as :

```
.flatMap(s -> s)
```

Comment: @AnandVaidya On a side note, all that logic within `map` shall reside in another function altogether to improve it further. And hopefully, none of it is modifying the current stream elements as well.

Comment: yes, I did that already to figure out the actual error. @nullpointer